# ng-model not working inside ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am a beginner in angularjs and currently I am facing an issue with ng-include.

I have a test app using partials.
Here is my code.

```
<html ng-app ="TextboxExample">
    <head>
        <title>Settings</title>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <div ng-include src = "'view.html'"></div>
        <script>
          angular.module('TextboxExample', [])
            .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
              $scope.textboxVal = 'fddfd';

              $scope.ReadGeneralSettings = function() {
                alert($scope.textboxVal);
              }
              $scope.ResetGeneralSettings = function() {

                $scope.textboxVal = 'fddfd';
              }

            }]);
        </script>
        <button class="pull-right" ng-click = "ReadGeneralSettings()">Read</button>
        <button class="pull-right" ng-click = "ResetGeneralSettings()">Cancel</button>



    </body>
</html>
```

The partial code view.html is

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textboxVal">
```

For some reason, textboxVal set to ng-model doesn't get updated when I enter the value in the text box.
But this works fine if I don't use ng-include and directly add the content of view.html into the main html file.
Please help.

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: ng-include creates a new scope

Comment: ok, so I can I make it work?

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use **$parent** to access the scope of the controller

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DWW2DiYHWDUKXLP9WGK3?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.textboxVal">
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `ngInclude` creates new scope, so the model you define inside partial template with `ngModel` works with local scope value, and outer `ExampleController` can't see it.

The simple solution is to use prototypical chain of scope objects, then inner scope will inherit and use model value from the outer scope:

```
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div ng-include src = "'view.html'"></div>
    <script>
      angular.module('TextboxExample', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.model.textboxVal = 'fddfd';

          $scope.ReadGeneralSettings = function() {
            alert($scope.model.textboxVal);
          }
          $scope.ResetGeneralSettings = function() {
            $scope.model.textboxVal = 'fddfd';
          }

        }]);
    </script>
    <button class="pull-right" ng-click = "ReadGeneralSettings()">Read</button>
    <button class="pull-right" ng-click = "ResetGeneralSettings()">Cancel</button>

</body>
```

and then use it in partial as

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.textboxVal">
```